# Duplicates in SQL result with many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I am downloading some data from twitter trough Twitter API and saving it to my postgresql database.

Im saving various informations from the tweets, but now I want to know how offten are some hashtags used together in a tweet.

I have tables: `hashtag`, `tweet_has_hashtag` and `tweet`. the `tweet_has_hashtag` is for the many-to-many relationship, betweet the `tweet` and the `hashtag`

The SQL in running is:

```
  select h1.txt, 
         h2.txt, 
         count(th1.tweet_id)
    from hashtag h1,
         tweet_has_hashtag th1, 
         tweet_has_hashtag th2, 
         hashtag h2
   where th1.hashtag_id = h1.id and 
         th2.tweet_id = th1.tweet_id and 
         th2.hashtag_id = h2.id and 
         h2.id <> h1.id
group by h1.id, 
         h2.id
order by count(th1.tweet_id) desc
   limit 1000
```

The result is fine, but tha hashtags are in different rows the same, but switched eg:

```
love    | me      | 925
me      | love    | 925
style   | fashion | 654
fashion | style   | 654
```

How can I get the result without the switched duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `h2.id <> h1.id` with `h2.id > h1.id` in your `WHERE`.

```
  SELECT h1.txt, 
         h2.txt, 
         COUNT(th1.tweet_id)
    FROM hashtag h1,
         tweet_has_hashtag th1, 
         tweet_has_hashtag th2, 
         hashtag h2
   WHERE th1.hashtag_id=h1.id 
         AND th2.tweet_id=th1.tweet_id 
         AND th2.hashtag_id=h2.id 
         AND h2.id > h1.id
GROUP BY h1.id, 
         h2.id
ORDER BY COUNT(th1.tweet_id) DESC
   LIMIT 1000;
```